# Do the rationals possess Archimedean property?

Tags: calculus

Since to prove the Archimedean property we need to use the completeness property and since the $\mathbb{Q}$ are not complete we can infer that $\mathbb{Q}$ do not possess the Archimedean property.

Comment: To prove the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, one can also use the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

But the rationals possess the Archimedean property...

Take $a = \frac{p_a}{q_a}$ and $b = \frac{p_b}{q_b}$, then clearly $a \times (q_a \times p_b) \geq p_b \geq b$

Archimedean property has nothing to do with completeness (you can have one without the other, none or both properties)

Comment: When i say the Archimedean property i mean the following: given any $a>0$ where $a$ is rational then there exists a natural No $n$ such that $n>a$.correct??

Comment: @chris : this is a very restrictive version of the Archimedean property. But it's easier to prove it : if $a$ is rational, then $a=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p$ and $q$ integers. Then you have $|p| \geq a$

Comment: @chris usually, the Archimedean property is this one : let $(A,+,\leq)$ a totally ordered group, then if we have $0\leq a\leq b$, there exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $b\leq na$  where $na := \underbrace{a+a+\cdots+a}_{n\text{ times} }$

Answer (score 1):

No, we can't infer that. We need completeness to prove the Archimedean property for $\Bbb R$; regardless of whether the word "need" is strictly correct there, we can't infer anything about $\Bbb Q$ from this.

In fact the Archimedean property for $\Bbb Q$ is completely trivial.

Comment: show me how you prove the Archimedean property in Q

Comment: REFER me to a well known book that proves the Archimedean property without using the completeness property

Comment: @chris You should really say PLEASE. The archimedean property for $\Bbb Q$ is trivial. A proof was sketched in the other answer. In excruciating detail: Suppose $r$ and $s$ are positive rationals; we want to show there exists an integer $n$ so $nr>s$. Say $r=a/b$, $s=c/d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers. Then $nr>s$ is equivalent to $n(ad)>bc$. But $ad\ge1$, so $n=bc+1$ works: $(bc+1)(ad)\ge bc+1>bc$.